# Where to put DB-accessing template helper functions in Django

Tags: django, templates, drop-down-menu

So I have a search page with result table. I have a drop down that's a filter from the DB. Instead of calling and populating this drop-down field filter at my view/index() method, can I just call a helper function that returns this list from the DB and populates the drop down at the template level?

I know about context_processors and my understand is that it's for the entire site, but I want this DB call to only happen on this particular page and no where else?

What do call this so I can try to find it in django docs.

Much Thanks

edit: to clarify more: the result table contains movies and drop-down filter is movie types (actions, adventure, thriller, etc). This list is made up from a "SELECT DISTINCT type FROM movies" query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django equivalent of helpers is [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/), and it's certainly appropriate to put db-accessing code there.

However, if it's only for a single page, I'm not sure why you wouldn't do it in the view.

Comment: ok helpers! maybe this will be used in other pages in the future. It's for organization "cleanliness" and aesthetics of code.

Comment: oh and another reason, my view can be called with ajax. if that's the case the result is different since a different template without the filters is returned (for asynchronous pagination), these subsequent ajax calls will be faster because less DB calls since I have a few of these "DB" filters.